# Token based authentication with different types of clients in C#

Tags: c#, oauth, asp.net-web-api2, token, wcf-security

I am working on a project where we have different type of clients (winform App, ASP.net mvc, WCF service).

I need to implement security in it. Here is my plan...

1. There will be one service (planning to create as WebApi) to authenticate user.
2. client app will pass Windows identity to this authentication service.
3. Service will return authentication Token to user.
4. This token will be passed to WCF service for each call.
5. WCF service will verify this token using authentication service.
6. If user has correct permissions, then WCF will perform requested action.
7. If token expire then WCF service will renew the token using Auth service.

I am planning to use attribute based programming for Security for each WCF call.

I gone through lots of articles online but could worked out it.

can anyone point me to some article where I an find below...

1. Generate token based on Windows Identity.
2. How to pass token to WCF service for each call.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using **Access Token** for authentication and **refreshtoken** to obtain renewed access token. You can store refreshtokens in database. If your scenario needs **multiple client/device** for each user then you will need to store **unique deviceId with refreshtoken**.Below helpful links for Access Token and RefreshToken:

[Token Based Authentication using ASP.NET Web API 2, Owin, and Identity](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)

[Enable OAuth Refresh Tokens in AngularJS App using ASP .NET Web API 2, and Owin](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/)